# Changing speed of the player by custom bound keys

Tags: quake-2

I'm trying to bind keys for making a huge jump and walking faster.

I added the following code in "autoexec.cfg" file:

```
alias "+fasterwalk"     "cl_forwardspeed 640;   +forward"
alias "+fastforward"    "cl_forwardspeed 4000;  +forward"
alias "+fastback"       "cl_backspeed    4000;  +back"
alias "-fasterwalk"     "-forward;  cl_forwardspeed 320"
alias "-fastforward"    "-forward;  cl_forwardspeed 320"
alias "-fastback"       "-back;     cl_backspeed    320"
alias "+longjump"       "+fastforward; wait; cl_upspeed 2000; +moveup; wait; -moveup; cl_upspeed 200; wait; -fastforward"
alias "-longjump"       "wait"

bind ALT "+longjump"
bind MOUSE2 "+fasterwalk"
bind UPARROW "+fastforward"
bind DOWNARROW "+fastback"
```

It doesn't work. When I press the ALT key, the player only jumps and lands to the exact same point. And when I press the second mouse button, the player moves forward with the default speed. Up and down arrow keys also make the player move at default speed.

It is like the `cl_forwardspeed #` and `cl_backspeed #` commands have no effect.

What am I doing wrong? How do I fix this configuration?

Comment: You might be going over the max speed limit. According to http://www.gamewinners.com/Cheats/index.php/Quake_2_(PC) its 500. Or if its on a server you need to enable cheating. Also with sv_maxspeed you see and can set the maxspeed. And just to be safe that your script is working at all: try your longjump script with +forward +moveup commands only and not any aliases.

Comment: Indeed the max movement speed is 500 with a default of 200 (walk) and 300 (run). Try setting cl_forwardspeed to a very low number like 100 and see if this gives you any noticeable effect - set it in console so you get any feedback and errors and then work onwards from there. As mentioned by @Philipp the various jumps will need to be combined with moving foward.

Comment: @kalina When I set `cl_forwardspeed` to `10` the player indeed moved very very slowly. I think the problem is what you said, there is a maximum speed limit. How do I change maximum speed? There was a `sv_maxspeed` variable in Quake 1, but it doesn't work in Quake 2.

Comment: Don't think you can - as you said the variable isn't present in Quake 2.

Comment: From what I read sv_maxspeed only works on hosted servers but not on local games.